# Selenium doesn't work with firefox 19.0.2

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm getting the following error with selenium web driver after upgrading firefox 19

```
WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile. Profile Dir:
```

is there any way to fix this apart from downgrading firefox

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Then upgrade. Firefox 19 support isn't until v2.31

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that selenium lost the profile config.

Try re-loading a brand new profile and see if this resolves your issue:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

or alternatively for a specific profile that you have already created in Firefox:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "Selenium"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => profile)
```